# How to find min or max in constant time using infinite # processors?

Tags: algorithms, parallel-computing

Given $ n $ numbers and an infinite number of processors can the min or max be found in constant time? Assume a shared memory architecture (all processors can write to a common shared memory) and the ability to perform concurrent writes

I have tried dividing up the numbers into groups of 2 each and then using $n/2$ processors at the first step and then $n/4$ processors on the output of the first step etc. I can't see how to make use of more than $n/2$ processors given that I have $\infty$ of them

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science! What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We do not want to just do your (home-)work for you; we want you to gain understanding. However, as it is we do not know what your underlying problem is, so we can not begin to help. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/594/the-return-of-the-homework-question) for a relevant discussion. If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]? You may also want to check out our [reference questions](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/599/).

Comment: Added what I've tried/come up till now. Would appreciate any hint from the community to get me beyond this.

Comment: Have you tried proving a lower bound?  You may want to look at circuit lower bounds. One word to google for is *depth* (and work) of problems.

Answer (score 4):

I managed to solve this so hoping it's alright to answer your own question.
Initialize to all elements off, an $n$ bit vector $A$ having a 1:1 mapping with the $n $ numbers. Compare each number against every other number on $n \choose 2$ processors. Each processor switches the bit corresponding to the smaller of its two elements to 1. Assumption is that the processors can do concurrent writes to $A$. The bit in $A$ remaining off denotes the maximum element.

This is $\Theta(1)$ (constant time) as the depth of the computational graph is independent of the number of elements. The work required is however $\mathcal {O(n^{2})}$.

Comment: Nice idea! However: 1) How do you initialize $n$ bits in $O(1)$ time? 2) How do you deal with conflicting writes? Many processors try to write the same bits at the same time! (That is to say, this will only work on [some very specific machine models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_random-access_machine), and not at all on others.) 3) How do you find the 0-bit(s) in constant time?

Comment: Can you not use $n$ processors each writing to a different location in the array to initialize it? For finding the 0 bit also can't we again use $ n$ processors each reading a different bit of $A$ and writing the index concurrently to a single location only if the corresponding bit is 0? Assumption is that there is no tie for the max element.

Comment: Yup, that might work.

Answer (score 0):

You can get constant time if you use n^2 processors. Basically, every processor makes 1 comparison and writes a 0 to a shared memory array of size n if their comparison is smaller. The index in the array with a 1 left in it at the end is the max.

Answer (score -1):

If you find max and min using recursion, then the best case complexity is O(log n). So, I think you can get constant time, by dividing the work into n parts and assigning each of that partition to a processor. Infinite processors can be used only when n is too large.

Comment: Did you mean "can get constont time" or "can't get constant time"?

Comment: *How* do you divide this work into $n$ parts that can be executed simultaneously?

Comment: Use divide and conquer to divide work just like merge sort! And I meant that the problem would require O(1) time!

Comment: I very much doubt O (1), that's why I asked. We want _one_ answer, so the work done by all the processors needs to be combined into one answer. If you use m processors, that takes O (log m) .